# Python - How to convert txt to excel file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to follow [How to convert txt to excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59946452/how-to-convert-txt-to-excel-file) however the problem seems to still be where it seems to write a start ID at the first column which I don't really want to. For now it looks like:

[image]

and this is what I am looking for:

[image]

What I have done is that I have written a code that read a txt file that looks like:

```
id,quanitity,bu,link
80379173,1000.0,045,https://helloworld.com/-80379173/
10290396,1000.0,045,https://helloworld.com/-10290396/
40379170,1000.0,045,https://helloworld.com/-40379170/
20379171,1000.0,045,https://helloworld.com/-20379171/
```

by a code:

import pandas as pd

```
    excel = 'Available-Online-ART.txt'

    df = pd.read_csv(excel, sep=',')

    column_indexes = list(df.columns)

    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df.drop(columns=df.columns[-1], inplace=True)

    column_indexes = dict(zip(list(df.columns), column_indexes))

    df.rename(columns=column_indexes, inplace=True)
    df.to_excel('output.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index=False)
```

but it seems like it still adds the first column but also removing the link at the end. I wonder how I can do it to make it works as the second picture?

Comment: I've read your file as csv and `df.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False)` gave me the result  which you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have overthought the problem:

```
df = pd.read_csv(excel, sep=',')
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

is enough...

Comment: Oh lord... It was actually that simple.. Oh wlel.! Thanks! :D