# how to convert txt file to excel in python

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

I have tried to convert ".txt to .xlsx" in Python. But I still can't do it. Keep getting this error message  (my text file's data is in json format.)

```
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read() 
a= data.decode("utf-8")
a.to_excel('james.xlsx')
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-88-5fe4ac7c8bc5> in <module>
----> 1 a.to_excel('james.xlsx')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

Comment: The Pandas `to_excel` method requires a data frame, not a string. (Tangentially, you are doing something wrong if you think you *want* Excel.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `a` is a string. You need to feed `data` into a pandas dataframe `df` and then `df.to_excel('james.xlsx')`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60397144/python-how-to-convert-txt-to-excel-file-using-pandas) for more details.

Comment: Please leave a comment instead of posting an answer when you find a duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: hi, may i ask some thing more. just realize what is the real problem of my code. have ".txt file" where the data inside is in json format 

May i know how to convert all those **".txt file" into excel** via python

I can't find the way to convert the .txt file into excel due to the format of data is in json so it can't be converted.

please help